# Opengl Quads not rendering

Tags: java, opengl, render, lwjgl

This is the problematic code:

```
glColor3f(1,1,1);
for(int x=0;x<125;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<10;y++){

        int p = levelArray[x][y];
        if(p == 0){
            break;
        }
        Texture t = pieces[1];
        t.bind();
        System.out.println(x*64+"|"+y*64 + " :: "+((x*64)+t.getTextureWidth())+"|"+((y*64)+t.getTextureHeight()));
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex2f(x*64,y*64);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex2f((x*64)+t.getTextureWidth(),y*64);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex2f((x*64)+t.getTextureWidth(),(y*64)+t.getTextureHeight());
            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        glEnd();    
    }
}
```

I am getting a print out, so I am reaching the glBegin, I have taken sample coordinates outputted by the print and drawn that quad the line above my first one shown here, using the exact same texture and it renders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have three glVertex2f calls where you should have four (inside the GL_QUADS). 
You have four glTexCoord2f, so this must be a type-o in your code.